# combining multiple regex groups with lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

How can I combine 3 regex patterns into 1 expression - if it is possible?
I want to get the first **th tag value** the **first** **td** tag **value** and the **id** from the **a** tag using a proper regex for this. I've been struggling for an hour to get them all in 1 expression.What would be the solution?

```
 regex for th tag:  
 th[^>]+l">([^<]+)</th  
 regex for td tag:  
 td>([^<]+)</td  
 regex for a tag:
 <a((?!</a).)id="([^"]+)"
```

I have a list of items like this snippet.

```
    ...
    <th scope="col">1X2</th>
    <th scope="col" class="goR">Odds</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="row1">
    <td>Fortuna Köln</td>
    <td class="prc "><label><a id="MarketGroupListComponent25-selection-38225206.1" />
    ...
```

Comment: what about a proper html parsing library which gives you way simpler extraction possibilities like: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax - Your regex is screwed if anyone adds a comment into the html table for example

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely check that out!

Comment: @zapl your parser is screwed if the html isn't properly written, for example with a non-closed p tag. A parser might be the best solution here, but isn't always the best solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
(?s)th[^>]+l">(.*?)<\/th>.*?<td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?<a id="(.*?)"
```

You need the `(?s)` modifier to make `.` match a newline.
The 3 desired strings are in groups 1, 2 and 3.

You don't need any lookahead in this case.

See it in [action](https://regex101.com/r/2gF9B0/2)

Note :

This Regex will fail for many weird cases, e.g. escaped `\"` in id or values containing `th` or `th`. 
If you know that the html is valid, you could use a [Java HTML parser](https://jsoup.org/) for a more complex query. This parser also could fail if html isn't valid or if the html structure has changed.

Comment: Any comment for the downvote? The question asked a Regex, I gave a Regex. Depending on the variability of file format, regex could be a good idea, a parser could be a better idea.